# How to make the jquery UI slider maintain scroll position on postback

Tags: jquery, user-interface, scrollbar

So I'm implementing a the Jquery UI slider on my page. The value of the slider bar is fed in as a parameter to a sql datasource. On a button click, the parameter is fed into the datasource and the gridview on the screen rebinds. The problem is that I would like the scrollbar to maintain its position so that users know what value was fed in as a parameter for the gridview they are currently viewing.

Here is my code for the scrollbar:

```
 <!--Slider bar for investment-->

 <div style="float:right;">
 <script type = "text/javascript">

     $(function () {
         $("#slider").slider({
             value: 100,
             min: 1,
             max: 200,
             step: 1,
             slide: function (event, ui) {                     
                 $("#hiddenInvestment").val(ui.value);
             }
         });
         $("#hiddenInvestment").val($("#slider").slider("value"));
     });        
    </script>

<div class="demo">
<p>
<asp:label runat="server" id="amountlabel" >Investment:    
</asp:label>    
<input name="hiddenInvestment" id="hiddenInvestment" />
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="percentlabel">%</asp:Label>
</p>
<div id="Div1"></div>
</div>
<div class="demo" style="width:100px;">
<div id="slider"></div>
</div>
```

The line that I assume I need to alter is the 'value: 100', but I'm not sure what I need to change it to. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a hidden field on the page. Before you `submit` the `form` for `postback` set this hidden field with `slider` value. On page load when you initialize the `slider` read the initial value from this `hidden` field. Try this

```
$(function () {
     $("#slider").slider({
         value: ($('#sliderVale').val() || 100),
         min: 1,
         max: 200,
         step: 1,
         slide: function (event, ui) {                     
             $("#hiddenInvestment").val(ui.value);
         }
     });
     $("#hiddenInvestment").val($("#slider").slider("value"));
 }); 


 $('form').submit(function(){
     $('#sliderVale').val($("#slider").slider("value"));
 });
```

Comment: Thanks Shankar for this suggestion. I definitely think its the right approach but there is still one problem. I used an input as my hidden field #sliderVale and it seems to refresh on postback as well, so it returns to null and the value of the slider defaults to 100. Any suggestions on why this might be?

Comment: nm i wasnt using the hidden field property. this works great thanks so much for your help